# FireDac - Why is the database path is limited to 128?

Tags: ms-access, delphi, 64-bit, firedac

I would like to execute a query when the database path is greater than 128. This is the need of some customer.

Example that doesn't work. The database path is greater than 128. I get the following error message :

> [FireDac][DatS]-32. Column overflow [CATALOG_NAME] variable length. Value Length- [219], Maximum column length - [128].

```
try
    Connection := TFDConnection.Create(Application);
    Connection.Params.Add('DriverID=MSAcc');
    Connection.Params.Add('Database=D:\donnees\TEST\GV\FireDacCheminLong\FireDacCheminLong\FireDacCheminLong\FireDacCheminLong\FireDacCheminLong\FireDacCheminLong\FireDacCheminLong\FireDacCheminLong\FireDacCheminLong\FireDacCheminLong\DC26.021248.PGOC.23.10.18_projCC45_dgn_topo.mdb');
    Connection.Name        := 'Test';
    Connection.Connected    := True;
    FDQuery := TFDQuery.Create(Application);
    FDQuery.Connection := Connection;
    FDQuery.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM PointTopo';
    FDQuery.Active:= True;

finally
    FDQuery.Active:= False;
    Connection.Connected := False;
    FreeAndNil(Connection);
    FreeAndNil(FDQuery);
end;
```

Example that works. The database path is less than 128

```
try
    Connection := TFDConnection.Create(Application);
    Connection.Params.Add('DriverID=MSAcc');
    Connection.Params.Add('Database=D:\donnees\TEST\GV\FireDacCheminLong\FireDacCheminLong\FireDacCheminLong\FireDacCheminLong\DC26.021248.PGOC.23.10.18_projCC45_dgn_topo.mdb');
    Connection.Name        := 'Test';
    Connection.Connected    := True;
    FDQuery := TFDQuery.Create(Application);
    FDQuery.Connection := Connection;
    FDQuery.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM PointTopo';
    FDQuery.Active:= True;
finally
    FDQuery.Active:= False;
    Connection.Connected := False;
    FreeAndNil(Connection);
    FreeAndNil(FDQuery);
end;
```

how to execute a query when the length of the database path is greater than 128 ?

Cyril

- Operating system : Windows 10 64 B
- R.A.D : Delphi 10.4
- Database : Access database (office 365)
- The Access Database Engine : accessdatabaseengine_2016_X64

Comment: Hi, Your question is very messy and hard to read. This makes it hard to understand too. Please update your question with some formatting, code and a proper explanation of what you're trying to do and what your issue is. If you do not put any effort into your question it discourages people from even attempting to read or answer your question.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer. I hope my post is more understandable.
I need to improve my English.

Comment: Hi, 
There is a solution to fix this problem.
There are 2 options in the FDConnection, TFDTable and TFDQuery components.
The FetchOptions.Cache and FetchOptions.Items options should have fiMeta set to false.

bye

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct solution, but a workaround. You could map the folder on the long path to a drive, so very_long_path_name simply becomes G:\ for example.